# Not able to export data in the original format using xlwt library(django)

Tags: python, sql, django, xlwt

When i am exporting sql query data in excel using xlwt in django, the NULL's are getting converted to blanks and Boolean values to True and False. But i want data to be exported as it is.

```
views.py

def download_consolidatedsheet(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form= ConsolidatedSheetDownloadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            countries=form.cleaned_data.get('countries')
            output=BytesIO()
            data = get_consolidated_data(countries)
            with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="ConsolidatedData", index=False)
                writer.save()
                filename = f"consolidated_data.xlsx"
                res = HttpResponse(
                output.getvalue(),
                content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                    )
                res['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
                return res
        # else:
        #     messages.error(request, 'Invalid form submission.')
        #     messages.error(request, form.errors)
    else:
        form = ConsolidatedSheetDownloadForm()
    
    return render(request, 'admin/consolidated_sheet_download.html',{'form':form})
```

controller.py

```
def get_consolidated_data(country):

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query = f"""    
            @sql_query@
           """
    
    #print (query)
    result_data=cursor.execute(query)
    result=dictfetchall(result_data)
    df=pd.DataFrame(result)
    
    return df
```

Comment: Can you give the code that you write?

Comment: @SharimIqbal I have added view and controller. Do i need to post anything else?

Comment: The question refers to xlwt but you are using xlsxwriter, is that right? Also, how do you want Null and Boolean values to appear in Excel, as strings or something else?

Comment: @jmcnamara xlsxwriter is correct i think , I am new to Django. I want NULL values to appear as NULL only(for NULL there is no specific datatype in sql but can be considered as Int ) and for Boolean i want them to be Boolean but as 0 and 1 as it is there in database and not TRUE and False.

Comment: In that case it it probably best to convert the NULL or None values to the string 'Null' (or whatever you want) and convert True/False to 1/0 (or whatever you want) in the dataframe. Then they will appear as you want in the Excel file.

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much.